# Replacing the content of a div depending on a click on another element (fiddle example)

Tags: jquery

I have got three boxes (box1, box2, box3). Box2 and box3 are the same, they just show a border when clicked on (selection). Only one item can be selected at the same time. I got this so far.

Now i would like that in box one appears a text where it says= " You clicked on..." and then there should be written "I am Box 1" or "I am Box 2".

I know it is probably a simply thing, but I just dont get it, I tried so many things now.

HTML:

```
<div class="showbox">

<a>
When I cklick on one of the yellow boxes, I would like the content of this element to be changed. The result should be "Okay, you chose Box 1 (or Box 2, depens on what I clicked on).
```

```
</div>

<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.showbox{
 height: 14rem;
 width: 14rem;
 background-color: grey;
 float:left;
}
.box{
  height: 4.5rem;
  width: 4.5rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 1rem;
}
#box1, #box2{
  float: left;
}
 .borderClass{  
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 
 }
```

JS:

```
var box1 = "I am Box 1";

$('.box').click( function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass('borderClass') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
  } else {
    $('.box').removeClass('borderClass');
    $(this).addClass('borderClass');    
  }
 });
```

Please look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/j7rdtqvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can add some attributes to your div elements, here you go:

```
<div class="box" id="box1" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2" data-id="2"></div>
```

and script should be:

```
$('.box').click( function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('borderClass') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
    } else {
        $('.box').removeClass('borderClass');
        $(this).addClass('borderClass');
    }

    if ($(this).data('id') == 1) {
        $('.showbox').html('Okay, you chose Box 1.')
    } else {
        $('.showbox').html('Okay, you chose Box 2.')
    }
});
```

But if you can't add any other attributes, this is the way:

```
$('.box').click( function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('borderClass') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
    } else {
        $('.box').removeClass('borderClass');
        $(this).addClass('borderClass');
    }

    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('box')[1];
    $('.showbox').html('Okay, you chose Box ' + id + '.')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code I just change the text based on click of box.

```
$('.box').click( function(){
   var box_number = 0;
     if( $(this).attr('id')== 'box1' ) {
    box_number = 1;
   }else if(  $(this).attr('id')== 'box2'  ){
    box_number = 2;
   }
   $(this).html('<p>Okay, you chose Box '+box_number+'</p>');

   if ( $(this).hasClass('borderClass') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('borderClass');
   } else {
      $('.box').removeClass('borderClass');
      $(this).addClass('borderClass');    
   }
});
```